# How to mock and read a cookie in xUnit?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit, xunit.net, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a method. In that, I am reading the cookie like below,

```
string cookieData = Request.Cookies["XXXX"];
```

the issue is while writing a xUnit I am getting a null. Can anyone please help me with how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should add a facade between your code and the reading of the cookie. Then you can mock the result from the facade. IE _myCookieFacade.Request("NameOfCookie)